# CSS positioning / need idea's

Tags: javascript, css

Guy's I'm a bit stick on this project. Trying to create a Google Calander page. Giving a function an array of objects each object having 2 properties, start and end, print the following to the screen.

[image]

I'm almost done.... this is what I have so far

I'm stock on the positioning. If I should make the inner div's absolute or relative. Because when I make them relative, they drop down to much, if I make the absolute, then having trouble aligning them correctly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="canv" class="canvas">
<!--                 <div class="event">
                    <h1>Sample Item</h1>
                    <p>Sample location</p>
                </div> -->
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <p>9:00 <span class="am">AM</span></p>
                <p class="thirty">9:30</p>
                <p>10:00 <span class="am">AM</span></p>
                <p class="thirty">10:30</p>
                <p>11:00 <span class="am">AM</span></p>
                <p class="thirty">11:30</p>
                <p>12:00 <span class="am">PM</span></p>
                <p class="thirty">12:30</p>
                <p>1:00 <span class="am">PM</span></p>
                <p class="thirty">1:30</p>
                <p>2:00 <span class="am">PM</span></p>
                <p class="thirty">2:30</p>
                <p>3:00 <span class="am">PM</span></p>
                <p class="thirty">3:30</p>
                <p>4:00 <span class="am">PM</span></p>
                <p class="thirty">4:30</p>
                <p>5:00 <span class="am">PM</span></p>
                <p class="thirty">5:30</p>
                <p>6:00 <span class="am">PM</span></p>
                <p class="thirty">6:30</p>
                <p>7:00 <span class="am">PM</span></p>
                <p class="thirty">7:30</p>
                <p>8:00 <span class="am">PM</span></p>
                <p class="thirty">8:30</p>
                <p>9:00 <span class="am">PM</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>

    var events = [ 
        {start: 30, end: 150}, 
        {start: 540, end: 600}, 
        {start: 560, end: 620}, 
        {start: 610, end: 670} 
    ];

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
    var totalElem = 0;
    var totalTop = 0;


    var total = events.forEach(function(event, index){
        var testArr = events;

        var test = testArr.length - index;
        if(index > 0 && test >=2 ){
            totalElem++
        }


    })


    function layOutDay(event){


        var newArr = event; 

        event.forEach(function(event, index){

            var env = document.createElement("div"),
            h1 = document.createElement("h1"),
            p = document.createElement("p"),
            sampleItem = document.createTextNode("Sample Item"),
            sampleLocation = document.createTextNode("Sample Location");

            p.appendChild(sampleLocation);
            h1.appendChild(sampleItem);

            env.className = "event";
            env.setAttribute('id', index)
            env.appendChild(h1);
            env.appendChild(p);
            canvas.appendChild(env);

//conversion
//totalTop = keeping track of start of each event
            var pixelsStart = (event.start * .86);

            pixelsEnd = ((event.end - event.start) * .86);

            totalTop += pixelsEnd;
            console.log(totalTop, 'test');

            env.style.top = pixelsStart + "px";
            env.style.height = pixelsEnd + "px";

// check start collide with previous event
                var test = newArr.length - index;

                if(index > 0 && test >=2 ){
                var start = event.start,
                    end = event.end,
                    check = newArr[index+1].start;

                    function between(check, start, end) {
                      return check >= start && check <= end;
                    }

                    if (between(check, start, end)) {
                        var newWidth = (96/totalElem)

                        env.style.width = newWidth + "%";
                    }
                }

            }) // end of loop

// correct placement
// 1. If 2 or more events - done
// 2. Grab values then check range
// 3. if within same range then run logic to divide with evently
// 4. else place elements as is

            // var newArr = document.getElementsByClassName("event");

            // if(newArr.length > 1){
            //     var start = obj.start;
            //     var end = obj.end;
            //     var check = checkObj.start

            //     var check = function between(check, start, end) {
            //       return check >= start && check <= end;
            //     }

            //     if (check(600, 560, 620)) {
            //         console.log('true')
            //     }


            // }
        }




layOutDay(events);   

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.canvas {
  background-color: #ECECEC;
  border-left: 2px solid #ABABAB;
  height: 620px;
  width: 720px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 300px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.am {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #ADADAD;
}

.thirty {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #ADADAD;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1100px;
}

.time {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

.event {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
  border-left: 3px solid #63AF8F;
  width: 96%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: 28px;
  height: 52px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.event h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #63AF8F;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.event p {
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #ADADAD;
}

/*# sourceMappingURL=../maps/style.css.map */
```

Comment: here is my jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=jOBEK3Fxv3

Comment: Interesting... I mean that was the design that I received from my client and the functionality he wants, I'm just trying to accomplish the task.

Comment: I apologize. I misunderstood your question. I thought the picture is what you currently have and you are asking us for better design ideas. Perhaps it has to do with the fact you did not provide a [mcve]. Or perhaps with the fact your question is not clear. I'm not entirely sure. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the position relative is fine, you need to check your 'top' and 'height' calculations based on start and end positions. 
Also, adjust margin positions to align properly. 
And can use wrapper div and give some padding there.